# Popup showing Gingerbread theme when executed from ICS

Tags: android

From a service, I am trying to show a toast irrespective of what application is there in the foreground. For this, I use an activity with theme as `Theme.Dialog`

Following is how I declare this in manifest:

```
    <activity android:process="@string/process" 
              android:name="com.android.blesettings.findmeserver.LaunchPopup" 
              android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```

Everything works OK except for the theme. The theme of the popup is that of Gingerbread(unsure why it happens!), though I run the application in ICS. How can I resolve this, such that the theme of popup shown is that of ICS instead of Gingerbread

Any help is appreciated

[image: Pop up displaying Gingerbread theme]

Comment: if you set no theme, it wouldn't pick the systems default?

Comment: then how would I specify this activity as popup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use **Holo** themes to match **ICS** style, like this: `Theme.Holo.Dialog` instead of `Theme.dialog`

But older API's doesn't support Holo theme. So, for your app to be compatible to older versions, you should define `styles.xml` file under `values-v14` folder (v14 = ICS)

**values-v14/styles.xml :**

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>      
</style>
```

**values/styles.xml :**

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>      
</style>
```

then, change your activity definition to this:

```
<activity android:process="@string/process" 
          android:name="com.android.blesettings.findmeserver.LaunchPopup" 
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
          android:theme="@style/DialogTheme" >
</activity>
```